# Function that saves to files produces an error

Tags: r, plot

I am writing a simple function that is suppsed to save two plot but unfortunetelly sth is wrong. How to make it work?

```
f1<-function(x){


write.table(as.matrix(summary(x)),file="dane.txt",sep=";",row.names=T)

#I want here to make two plots.
    png(filename="hist.png")
    hist(x)
    dev.off

    dev.cur()
    png(filename="density.png")
    plot(density(x))
    dev.off
    }
```

As a result of calling this function I get this message:

```
function (which = dev.cur()) 
{
    if (which == 1) 
        stop("cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)")
    .External(C_devoff, as.integer(which))
    dev.cur()
}
<bytecode: 0x0000000010dbfaa8>
<environment: namespace:grDevices>
```

Comment: Change dev.off to dev.off()

Comment: still the same message

Comment: Okay, my fault. It works. Kunal Puri - you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code like so

```
f1<-function(x){
  write.table(as.matrix(summary(x)),file="dane.txt",sep=";",row.names=T)

  #I want here to make two plots.
  png(filename="hist.png")
  hist(x)
  dev.off()

  dev.cur()
  png(filename="density.png")
  plot(density(x))
  dev.off()
}
```

You only missed the () of dev.off()

Comment: You are right, thank you for the answer.